# What is the best way to allow API calls to run code on an EC2 instance in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have built a command line tool in Python that logins to a site and downloads files it is ran like this

```
./my_scraper.py -user "username" -pass "passwd" -start 91  -end 42 -preset "Cancelled" -url "www.mysite.com`
```

The code is hosted on an EC2 instance and ran daily with a crontab, I want to allow another user to make changes to how the tool is ran through an API, for example using a different username, password or url

I was thinking about using API Gateway and Flask endpoints but would like to hear if anybody has other suggestions?

Comment: The easiest way, if the tool already runs on an EC2 box, is to just let them run the command with `ssh`. `ssh someuser@somebox ./my_tool.py ....`.

Comment: I'd like to have the use of an API so they don't have to always ssh to change things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use 'API Gateway' and 'Lambda' - the user will be able to pass params to to your code (which will be implemented as Lambda) .

The user will pass the params via HTTP call to the 'API Gateway'.

Going in this direction (if possible - I have no idea what my_tool.py is doing..) will cause everything to run serverless. There will be no need for EC2 instance.

Comment: Ive added detail about what my_tool.py in the post, I will look into lambda! thanks dude